# CSS3 transition in phpstorm

Tags: css, phpstorm

I use phpstorm, but in the CSS file it won't work for code completion like `-webkit-translate`, `translate` or `animation`.
What should I do?

Comment: Check this and related tickets: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-105

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed in new versions of PHPStorm.